# Avoiding the loops - 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Background: I have 1680 images: 7 users, each present 10 times one of 24 English letters in sign language.

I'm trying to change the specification of the image from the letter to an array of size 24 for each image, containing one `1` in the position of the letter. for example, if the letter is `A`, ther will be `1` in the first index and `0` is the 23 other indexes.

I'm trying to avoid loops this way:

```
def one_hot_encoding(images_array, user_array):
    letters_to_ones = np.zeros((len(user_array), len(images_array[0]), number_of_classes))
    for letter in range(number_of_classes):
        letters_to_ones[0:len(user_array)][(10*letter) : (10*letter + 9)][letter] = 1
```

Note: number of classes defined before and it equals to 24.

I get an error:

> index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: How about using https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
number_of_classes = 24 
n_users = 7
n_images = 1624
letters_to_ones = np.zeros((n_users, n_images, number_of_classes))
for letter in range(number_of_classes):
    letters_to_ones[:, (10*letter) : (10*letter + 9), letter] = 1
```

Don't reindex the array by doing `a[1:2][3:4][5:6]`. Instead, use multiple indexing, as I have above: `a[1:2, 3:4, 5:6]`. Your first slice index does not do what you think it does, in fact your second slice also indexes in the first dimension. Here is what I mean

```
a = np.zeros((4,3,2))
res = a[:4]
print(res.shape)
# => (4, 3, 2)
```

Note how if we added more slices, e.g `res = a[:4][:2]`, the second slice still indexes the first dimension.